Building a generic search for RavenDb - failing to create Expression<Func<T,object>>
The standard search method on IRavenQueryable looks like this:
public static IRavenQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> self, Expression<Func<T, object>> fieldSelector, string searchTerms, decimal boost = 1m, SearchOptions options = SearchOptions.Guess, SearchOperator @operator = SearchOperator.Or)
{
    MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    return (IRavenQueryable<T>)self.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(null, method, self.Expression, fieldSelector, Expression.Constant(searchTerms), Expression.Constant(boost), Expression.Constant(options), Expression.Constant(@operator)));
}

The full source of the method can be found here
I'd like to create another extension method that allows me to specify which property to search on using its name. So I came up with this
public static IRavenQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> self, string fieldName, string searchTerms, decimal boost = 1m, SearchOptions options = SearchOptions.Guess, SearchOperator @operator = SearchOperator.Or)
{
    MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    var info = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        ?? throw new Exception($"{fieldName} is not a valid property on {typeof(T).Name}");
    var parTarget = Expression.Parameter(info.DeclaringType, "target");
    var exprGetter = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(info.DeclaringType, typeof(object)), Expression.Property(parTarget, info), parTarget);
    return (IRavenQueryable<T>)self.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(null, method, self.Expression, exprGetter, Expression.Constant(searchTerms), Expression.Constant(boost), Expression.Constant(options), Expression.Constant(@operator)));
}

If I call this, I'm getting an ArgumentException (the Search I'm making is on T being NoSqlModels.PhoneBookCategory, and the property used in fieldName is of type string)

System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type
'System.Func2[NoSqlModels.PhoneBookCategory,System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String' of method  'Raven.Client.Documents.Linq.IRavenQueryable1[NoSqlModels.PhoneBookCategory]
Search[PhoneBookCategory](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[NoSqlModels.PhoneBookCategory],
System.String, System.String, System.Decimal,
Raven.Client.Documents.SearchOptions,
Raven.Client.Documents.Queries.SearchOperator)' (Parameter
'arguments1')'

So it seems that my exprGetter returns an Expression<T,string>, rather than the required Expression<T,object>. So what do I need to change to get this to work

So it seems that my exprGetter no ... you are calling the same method with wrong parameters ... The error is clear EXPRESSION(...) cannot be used for parameter of type STRING ... not Expression<T, string> cannot be used ... as  Expression<T, object>

obviously MethodInfo method; should point to your old Search not to iself

or just call old Search in your new Search after translating fieldName to the expression

From the Exception, yeah it's trying to call itself. What I fail to understand is why. The original implementation I posted (which is working) is also an extension method and works fine.

What I fail to understand is why  ... that's why => MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(); ... just call old Search with exprGetter ...

I just reused what was already there in RavenDB's own extension method. I figured they'd know what they're doing (since it's working and all). How would you write it then? Any Search that exists in the RavenDb namespace is just an extension method, there's no Search method to call on any class, static or instance.

just added a link to the source repo so you can see the original with all that's around it

again ... call other Search (just as line 987) .... and change exprGetter  to Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(parTarget, info), parTarget)

Here's a solution that strips much of the complexity of the original approach:
public static IRavenQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> self, string fieldName, string searchTerms, decimal boost = 1m, SearchOptions options = SearchOptions.Guess, SearchOperator @operator = SearchOperator.Or)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);
    expGetter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, P>>(property, parameter);
    return self.Search(expGetter, searchTerms, boost, options, @operator);
}

It just generates the field selector, then calls the original extension method.
